# Why Required to chage X86 Platform in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am trying to use [this article project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3582/Word-Control-for-NET?fid=14182&df=10000&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=76#xx0xx) in to my WindowsForm application.

I am using visual studio 2010.
You can download and run test application at above link.

My problem is when I use list of below DLLs in my project.

```
Interop.Office.dll

Interop.VBIDE.dll

Interop.Word.dll
```

I have to change project configuration settings.

**Configuration Manager (open from Solution configuration combo box near Run button) => Platform => to x86.**

1. Why we should have to change platform to x86?
2. If I change platform to x86? Will project run on 64bit machine?

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

It's because your C# program's memory model must match that of any unmanaged DLLs that you want to call. Because the Microsoft Office DLLs are 32-bits, so must your program be.

It will still run fine on a 64 bit machine, though!

Comment: thanks for replying... 
BTW, ... DLL i have listed above are available in 64bit version? if yes please suggest me

Comment: I think they are, but only if you've installed the 64-bit version of Office. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.100%29.aspx But then I'm not sure how you handle supporting both 32 bit and 64 bit without two builds of your program.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will change to x86 because you use platform depended dlls.
2. Yes, it will run as WOW64.